# Passing a function directly to a change() event does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to show or hide some divs according the value selected of a select. To do this, I have this block of code that works great:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
      function formaCaptacao()
      {
            $('.receptivo').parent().hide();
            $('.indicacao').parent().hide();
            $('.interna').parent().hide();
            var a = $('#cp-forma-captacao').val();
            console.log(a);

            switch( $('#cp-forma-captacao').val() ) {
                  case 'contato_receptivo':
                        $('.receptivo').parent().show();
                        break;
                  case 'indicacao':
                        $('.indicacao').parent().show();
                        break;
                  default:
                        $('.interna').parent().show();
                        break;
            }
      }

      formaCaptacao();

      $('#cp-forma-captacao').change(function(){
            formaCaptacao();
      });
});
```

On the bottom, when user changes the select value, I have to pass a function as parameter to the event `change()`. I tried this:

```
$('#cp-forma-captacao').change( formaCaptacao() );
```

But it does not work. It's like the `change()` event is never been called. Why? I'm just passing a function as parameter. Theoretically, it should work.

Comment: Try removing the parentheses from the function name when calling it inside the `.change()` like this: `$('#cp-forma-captacao').change( formaCaptacao );`

Comment: `$('#cp-forma-captacao').change(formaCaptacao);`

Comment: $('#cp-forma-captacao').change( formaCaptacao );  Using parentheses you execute the function and so apply to the change handler the result. In your case it's undefined.

Comment: That's it. Now I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you're invoking the function instead of passing the reference to the function itself - so what you're actually passing into `change()` is the result of calling `formaCaptacao` (which will be `undefined`, since it never returns anything), not the function itself.

Try this instead...

```
$('#cp-forma-captacao').change(formaCaptacao);
```

If you think of it as though you're doing this...

```
var formCaptaco = function() { console.log('example!'); }
$('#selector').change(formCaptacao);
```

...it might make more sense (it's actually slightly more complicated than that in reality, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) for a description of the differences).

Comment: I see. Now I really undestand how this works. I don't know who downvoted. It was not me. I upvoted.